# how to implement aws oAuth in angular project with cognito and lambda function or only with angular

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth, amazon-cognito

can anyone tell that how to implement oAuth functionality to my angular application connected with aws lambda and apigateway.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple/sample AngularV4-based web app that demonstrates different API authentication options using Amazon Cognito and API Gateway with an AWS Lambda and Amazon DynamoDB.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-apigw-angular-auth